# Error: task completion callback called too many times

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm compiling Typescript files into Javascript from different sources to different destinations. I need to know when all the compilations are done to run the task `minifyJS`.

The issue is that I get the error : `Error: task completion callback called too many times`. Which is right, but how am I suppose to manage this ?

```
gulp.task('compileTS', function (done) {
    // Compile pages
    pump([
        gulp.src(paths.componentsTS),
        typescript({
            target: 'ES5'
        }),
        gulp.dest(paths.dest)
    ], done);

    // Compile services
    pump([
        gulp.src(paths.servicesTS),
        typescript({
            target: 'ES5'
        }),
        gulp.dest(paths.dest + 'Services/')
    ], done);

    // Compile tests
    pump([
        gulp.src(paths.testsTS),
        typescript({
            target: 'ES5'
        }),
        gulp.dest(paths.destTestsJS)
    ], done);
});

// This task needs to be called after 'compileTS' is done
gulp.task('minifyJS', ['compileTS'], function () {
    pump([
        gulp.src([paths.dest + paths.allJS]),
        uglify(),
        rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }),
        gulp.dest(paths.dest)
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Please can you post your gulpfile.js in full, and I can run this locally and post a solution for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some counter (e.g. `remains`) to track completness:

```
gulp.task('compileTS', function (done) {
    var remains = 0;
    // Compile pages
    remains++;
    pump([
        gulp.src(paths.componentsTS),
        typescript({
            target: 'ES5'
        }),
        gulp.dest(paths.dest)
    ], completed);

    remains++;
    // Compile services
    pump([
        gulp.src(paths.servicesTS),
        typescript({
            target: 'ES5'
        }),
        gulp.dest(paths.dest + 'Services/')
    ], completed);

    remains++;
    // Compile tests
    pump([
        gulp.src(paths.testsTS),
        typescript({
            target: 'ES5'
        }),
        gulp.dest(paths.destTestsJS)
    ], completed);

    function completed () {
        if (--remains===0) {
            done(null, '');
        }
    }
});
```

Handling of errors I kept for you.

Comment: I thought of this solution. I guess I'll go for it, that's too bad there is no "gulp solution" to this.